# TableView disappears after segue unwind

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out, would like some insight into what's happening here:

I have a custom `UITableViewController` that's embedded in a `navigation controller`, and it has a button that triggers a segue to a plain `UIViewController`.

The plain `UIViewController` has a button that unwinds to the `TableViewController`, as well as a "back" button that's given for free thanks to `navigation controller`.

Now the issue: When I segue from `TableViewController` to `UIViewController`, everything works. From `UIViewController`, if I press the "back" button, it winds back and the `TableView` is reloaded automatically. HOWEVER, when I press the button that is linked to `@IBAction` to unwind, it unwinds to the `TableViewController` but nothing shows up, not even an empty table.

My debug view showed that once I tried to unwind using my button (not "back), `TableViewController` came back on screen but its frame was super small and nothing was in it, so the black background of the `navigation controller` was showing, thus just a black screen where the table should be.

Can anyone tell me how to manually reinitialize the `tableView` or reset the `TableViewController` when I unwind? I tried `tableView.reload()` in `viewDidAppear()` and nothing happened, as I suspect the problem is the `TableViewController` itself not having the original frame as before segueing.

[Link to screenshots with descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s14Ya.jpg)

TableViewController code:

```
class StatsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    //variable stuff

    @IBAction func unwindToRoot(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getData()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        self.getData()
    }   

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return solves.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! StatsTableViewCell
        cell.timeLabel?.text = solves[indexPath.row].0
        cell.scrambleLabel?.text = solves[indexPath.row].1
        return cell
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Delegate Datasource Methods
 //Add this two lines in viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.getData()

        //Add this line
        self.UITableViewName.delegate = self
        self.UITableViewName.dataSource = self

    }
```

Comment: Didn't work, the delegate and datasource were already linked in the Storyboard. Also, as I understand it, when unwind happens viewDidLoad() is not called, it's the viewDidAppear() that gets called

Answer (score 0):

You are using this two methods in statusTableViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "SelectionSegue" {
                //Your code
            }
        }

        @IBAction func unwindToThisView(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
            // set Delegate datasource method
        }
```

set outlet for unwindToThisView button to see the images

1.Click exit button for last ViewController
[image]

see Presenting Segues outlet for the Back Button
[image]

set action for back button

[image]

Comment: The action was already set when I checked my storyboard, can you elaborate on what you mean by "set outlet for unwindToThisView button to see the images"?

Comment: for the above code to placed on the your StatusTableViewController.swift and go to storyBoard to click another Viewcontroller Exit button you will see Presenting Segues like 2nd image and you click and drag to set action for back button.@dinosaysrawr

Comment: the exit is already done, the action does show up and does unwind back to the tableviewcontroller, but the tableview does not show up. It says the tableview is loaded when I check with the bool, but nothing shows up